# Вывод BigDecimal/Integer в необходимом формате

Tags: java, конвертация, bigdecimal

Буду признателен за совет, так как пока в голову приходят лишь костыльные решения.

Дано : BigDecimal - куда могут приходит 4-5 знаковые числа вроде :
5567.66, 10345.34, 88930.79

Есть ли возможность не извращаясь обеспечить вывод этих чисел в следующем формате:

5 567.66

10 345.34

88 930.20

То есть добавить пробелы.

**
На вход идет BigInteger.
На выход я отдаю String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); //Можно RU добавить ..
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(4543.34);
    String s = nf.format(bigDecimal);
```

4 543,34 ₽ - то что я и искал ...